# Sequelize insert data with primary key from json files

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, sequelize.js

**What I want**
First, I use COPY command to Postgresql database and export them into many json files by table.
Each json file contain an array of objects, each object is from each row of table, each object also include its primary key 'id'.
Then, I insert data from those json files into an empty database. 
Finally, I want to insert other data succefully, any warning about duplicate primary key won't happen.

**DB Schema**
Users

```js
    id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
```

Comments

```js
    id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        references: {
            model: 'Users',
            key: 'id'
        }
    },
    comment: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
```

**Json Files**
Users.json

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo" 
  }
]
```

Comments.json

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
        "userId": 1,
    "comment": "hi" 
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
        "userId": 1,
    "comment": "hey" 
  }
]
```

**What I tried and error showed**
I tried these methods to create data from json files, but got the same error message at further insert.
method 1:

```js
const insertData = [{id: 2, name: 'ofo'}]
Users.bulkCreate(insertData)
```

method2:

```js
const insertData = [{id: 2, name: 'ofo'}]
for (let i = 0; i < insertData.length; i++) {
    Users.create(insertData[i])
}
```

method3:

```sql
INSERT INTO "Users"
SELECT *
FROM json_populate_recordset(null::"Users", json [{id: 2, name: 'ofo'}]);
```

The error message said:
`error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"`
`detail: 'Key (id)=(1) already exists.'`

I also tried other methods to update primary key value, but got these error messages
method4:

```js
sequelize.query(`select make_serial('public', 'Users', 'id');`)
```

error message:
`error: function make_serial(unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist`
`hint: 'No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.'`

method5:

```js
sequelize.query(`CREATE SEQUENCE user_id_seq OWNED BY "Users".id;
                                SELECT SETVAL(user_id_seq, (SELECT MAX(id) FROM "Users"));`)
```

error message:
`error: column "users_id_seq" does not exist`

**version**
Postgresql: 14.5
sequelize: 5.22.4

**What problem need to help**
I want to know that there is any method to insert data from json file that `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"` this error won't happend.
Otherwise, there is any method I make postgresql to update primary key value.

Hope to get any suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I run this code to update id as primary to max value

```sql
SELECT SETVAL(E'\"user_id_seq\"', max(id)) FROM "Users";
```